# How to fix error about Outlook pst file?

Tags: outlook

When I am trying to open Outlook the error came like:

> filename.pst is not a personal folder”.

So I created one new pst and set it as default. Then I was able to open Outlook. But I need old emails which are in the old filename.pst file. And I need the old pst to be configured in my mail. When I tried the attached error coming.

Kindly suggest solution.

Comment: Use scanpst.exe and fix the .pst, search your office installation folder for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft provides the **Inbox Repair Tool** for correcting most problems with damaged Personal Folders **.pst** files. If you do not see the **Inbox Repair Tool** on the `Start menu, under Programs | Accessories | System Tools`,

use `Start | Find or Start | Search (depending on your operating system)` to search your system for `Scanpst.exe`.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/272227

You will need to know the location of the **.pst** file that you want to repair. See Outlook & Exchange/Windows Messaging Backup and Dual-Boot for information on file locations and ways to determine the location of a .pst file that you can see in Outlook.

Look at this reputable source also for help. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/...rclientslegacy

Answer (score 0):

You can go to File > Open to open the old .pst file and view the emails. You can also use the Import/Export option to import the messages into your new PST file if you would like.